# How to get variables from the outside, inside a function in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to figure out how can I get variables from the outside in a function, inside a function in jQuery but i get `Uncaught ReferenceError: myvar is not defined`. Is there any way of doing this?

A simple example of my code:

```
$(function(){
    var myvar = "stackoverflow";
});

$(function(){
    alert(myvar);
});
```

But when I define the variable outside the function it works:

```
var myvar = "stackoverflow";

$(function(){
    alert(myvar);
});
```

Why?

Any help is appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: thats the way it works . read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/javascript-variable-scope

Comment: Yep, read about JS scope.

Comment: Functions create scope. Variables declared with `var` are *local* to that function and cannot be accessed outside of it. The variable even only exist an the moment the code runs (assuming no closures).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The reason the second example works is because you're defining `myvar` as a global variable (which is accessible from anywhere).

The first example doesn't work because the variable is defined within functional scope (meaning it's inaccessible from all except that function's scope, and the scope of functions defined within that parent function's scope).

As stated in the comments, this is just how JavaScript works.  If this is a problem you're running into then it's probably time to rethink your architecture.

One common pattern is to define *shared* variables as properties of parent objects or functions.  For example:

```
$(function() {
    var funcOne = function() {
        this.sharedVal = 'stack overflow';
    };
    var funcTwo = function() {
        console.log(funcOne.sharedVal);
    };
});
```

This way you can have distinct functions that are able to share their properties from within other within other functions, whilst also keeping the global namespace clean.  Note, however, that in this example, a simple `var x = 'something';` which isn't bound as a property of another function would do just as well.

Answer (score 15):

Its all about scoping, in your second example myvar is in the global scope whereas in the first its contained in the function.

You can force it to be global though:

```
$(function(){
  window.myvar = "stackoverflow";
});

$(function(){
  alert(myvar);
});
```

(assuming this is in the browser)

Comment: It should probably be noted that this is a *horrible* practice...  That being said, to my knowledge this is the only way of achieving what the OP has asked for, so +1.

Comment: :) of course, never do this, but its possible

Answer (score 4):

The is due to scope of variable. Variable defined in $(function() has scope inside the this function. The enclusre here descide the scope. The variable defined outside function have global scope and defined in window object.

Scope inside function.

```
$(function(){
    var myvar = "stackoverflow";
});
// myvar is not accessible here.
```

Scope inside window object.

```
$(function(){
    window.myvar = "stackoverflow";
});

// myvar is accessible here.
```

Answer (score 1):

When you declare the variable inside  function .It has its scope limited to that function only(In case one of your scenario).

To access them everywhere outside function you need to declare it as global variable. Which is second case.