# How do I can access an outside function varible, inside a function in javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, variables, scope

I've a `percent` variable in my *javascript*, that variables is passing result from PHP.

#### This is the javascript:

#### test.js

```
console.log(percent); //* //variable was passed from PHP

function displayLoading() {
    console.log(percent); //**
}
```

If I use *`console.log(percent)` out the function it will print_out the value of `percent` in console. But if I use **`console.log(percent)` inside the `displayLoading` function, it will print_out as *`undefined`*.

How I can access the outside `variable` inside a function?

#### I've tried this way

from [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21453029/how-to-get-variables-from-the-outside-inside-a-function-in-jquery)

```
var funcOne = function() {
    this.sharedVal = percent;
};
var funcTwo = function() {
    console.log(funcOne.sharedVal);
};
```

and give print_out *`undefined`* into console log.

#### and

from [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16942043/access-variable-outside-function-scope)

```
var per = percents
console.log(per);   //this line print_out the value into console log

function displayLoading() {
   console.log(per);    //this print_out "undefined" into console log.
   var myPercent = per;
   console.log(per);    //and also print_out "undefined" into console log.
}
```

Both of code above didn't work for me, any one know another way?
Any help is appreciated, thanks :)

### EDITED:

The `percents` inside javascript above, I get from this code:

#### headerController.php

```
<?php
   $percent = $percent + 10;
?> 
    <script type="text/javascript">
       var percents = <?= $percent; ?>;
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../web/js/test.js"></script>
```

The main problem has found, the reason why I got `undefined` is because I print_out the `percents` right before the variable has passed from php.

#### How do I can pass php variable directly into a function in javascript file (test.js in this case)?

Comment: in which statement you are asigning value in percent?

Comment: Maybe, you're assigning the variable locally, try assigning it outside then  use console.log(window.percent); inside the function

Comment: `I've tried this way` - except you didn't, not really

Comment: this little code snippet is not enough to determine the problem. If percent is a global var (can't see how it's being defined, so who knows) then the very first code snippet should work fine

Comment: I'm sorry about the code, I have update my question. Check it :) Thanks

Comment: I guess the main problem here is that you call the variable before it's being set, so to test that out, use a timeout function for example `setTimeout(function(){ displayLoading(); }, 3000);` then see what you will get

Comment: @MostafaOmar Yeah your'e right, I call the function through button. And I exexute the function first before  the php variable pass to javascript. Ok, I'll try

Answer (score 0):

Define a global variable.

```js
percent = 'foobar';
// window.percent = 'foobar'; /* same thing */

function showthing() {
  console.log(percent);
}

showthing();
```

Comment: Yah, thanks. I've try and it's work. But I make a mistake, the problem cause is I call the function when the php variable not passed yet to javascript.

Answer (score 0):

try removing `var` from `var per = percents`. like this

```
per = percents
console.log(per);   //this line print_out the value into console log

function displayLoading() {
   console.log(per);    
   var myPercent = per;
   console.log(per);    
}
```

Comment: Why you declare `myPercent`?

Comment: that's not needed. i just copied and  your code .  all thing you have to do is 
change  var per = percents to  per = percents

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which console (browser or JS REPL - however they are almost same) are you talking about, but REPL always outputs the return value of a function. 
I don't think it's about global/local scope, as it's stated above.

```
>> p = 5; function dl() { console.log(p); }
<- 5
>> dl()
   5 
<- undefined
>> foo = function() { return "foo" }
<- function foo()
>> foo()
<- "foo"
```

Comment: I'm using mozilla log console, that is REPL console result above?

Comment: this is also from mozilla's web console from developer tools.

Answer (score 0):

A variable:

1) Declared with `var` keyword has local scope where it is declared.(if you declared it outside function you can not use it inside function and vice versa.

Example:

```
   var  percent = 'foobar';
    function showthing() {
      console.log(percent);//wrong
    }
    console.log(percent);//correct
```

2) Declared within particular function has local scope within function.

Example:

```
     function showthing() {
     var  percent = 'foobar';
      console.log(percent);//correct
    }
console.log(percent);//wrong
```

Comment: Thanks for the knowledge :)

Answer (score 0):

Is it a problem with the way you pass the variable from PHP, like AJAX? When you call displayLoading() the AJAX call may not have answered yet.

Comment: Yeah, you're right :D. I call the function when the variable not passed yet. May be you know how I can pass directly into a function in javascript?

Comment: You could do something like this if you use jQuery: 
$.get( "ajax/test.php", function( data ) {
displayLoading();
});

Comment: Thanks, I'm just learn about javascript / jquery. May I know exactly where I've tu put this code? inside _php controller_ code with `<script>....</script>` or in my _test.js_?

Comment: In your javascript file. But my suggestion is to rather change the order of lines than adding new code. In the block of code where you do the AJAX, after you get the value for your variable, call that function displayLoading. If you wish to simply combine JS with PHP: Your HTML file should be a PHP file, right? So you write in the header or footer of HTML <script>myVar = <?php echo $anotherVar; ?>;</script>